# Is it possible to alias an entire namespace in java?

Tags: java

My use case is fairly simple. I have a legacy piece of software that uses javax.comm (that is, I don't have the source). This software needs to run on a 64-bit version of Linux. This in turn means that rxtx is the only thing that will really work, but though rxtx is a drop-in for javax.comm, it uses the gnu.io namespace.

In python, I would create javax/com.py, and in it I would say "from gnu.io import *" and we'd be done, as python does allow you to rather messily import symbols from a module that imports them from elsewhere.

Because I haven't coded in Java in 11 years, I'm a bit lost. The only thing that comes to mind right now, is to write a shim-package that lives in javax.comm, which is merely empty classes that does nothing except inherit from their counterpart in gnu.io.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Another way that comes to mind (not necessarily a better way mind you) is to butcher the rxtx jar to change the actual packages in the bytecode. There's no clean way to create a package alias though.

Comment: It appears my plan of making a mirror package is not going to work either. Unfortunately CommPortIdentifier's constructor isn't public. So that's the end of the shim idea. I'll just have to reorganise rxtx so it actually lives in javax.comm, it seems.

Comment: I ended up re-organising the patched rxtx package from the arduino github account back into the javax.comm namespace. It appears to work just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you.